# CK Editor - possible for Font Size button to recognize px *or* pt?

Tags: ckeditor

Our CKEditor use case: we're importing hundreds of pre-existing client documents into our system.

These docs were *not* created using CKEditor.

However, they *will* be viewed and modified using CKEditor.

Problem:

- Some documents use only points, for example:
  `<p style="font-size: 11pt;">...</p>`
- Some documents use only pixels, for example:
  `<p style="font-size: 14px;>...</p>`
- Some documents use *both* units, for example:
  `<p style="font-size: 12pt;">...</p>, <span style="10px">...</span>`

Is it possible for the Font Size button to somehow recognize and display (depending on the text currently in focus) either the pt number *or* the px number on the button?

Answer (score 3):

I actually figured out the answer to my own question, which is to do this:

`CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_sizes = "8px/8px;8pt/8pt;9px/9px;9pt/9pt;10px/10px;10pt/10pt;11px/11px;11pt/11pt;12px/12px;12pt/12pt;14px/14px;14pt/14pt;16px/16px;16pt/16pt;18px/18px;18pt/18pt;20px/20px;20pt/20pt;22px/22px;22pt/22pt;24px/24px;24pt/24pt;26px/26px;26pt/26pt;28px/28px;28pt/28pt;36px/36px;36pt/36pt;48px/48px;48pt/48pt;72px/72px;72pt/72pt;";`

Now docs imported into CKEditor that use either px *or* pt units will be recognized by the Font Size button.

---

Additionally, text in our imported docs occasionally has *no* px or pt attribute, and is just 'un-marked-up' text in a default size.  In that case, this can be done to display a default text size and style on the Font Text and Font Style buttons:

`CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '14px';`

`CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = 'Arial';`